# Handling Terraform AMI looking returning an empty list

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a better way than the following to handle a Terraform data resource aws_ami_ids returning an empty list?

Always want the module to return the latest AMI's ID if found.

If the list was empty I was getting a "list "data.aws_ami_ids.full_unencrypted_ami.ids" does not have any elements so cannot determine type." error, so this was the workaround.

```
       data "aws_ami_ids" "full_unencrypted_ami" {
          name_regex  = "${var.ami_unencrypted_regex}"
          owners = ["123456789","self"]
       }

       locals {
         notfound = "${list("AMI Not Found")}"
         unencrypted_ami = "${concat(data.aws_ami_ids.full_unencrypted_ami.ids,local.notfound)}"
       }

       output "full_ami_unencrypted_id" {
         description = "Full Unencrypted AMI ID"
         value       = "${local.full_unencrypted_ami[0]}"
       }
```

Comment: What are you doing if the AMI is not found? Do you need to handle that in some way or can you just let Terraform error?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR was originally using the aws_ami_id resource but errors on an empty result, aws_ami_ids return an empty list, but the calling code is expecting an AMI ID so would need refactoring to handle a list and if it's empty or not.
I'd expect the terraform to fail later when the "AMI Not Found" Id would be used in an ASG etc.

Comment: And what does the calling module do with the empty list? Does it default to some random AMI? If it can't sensibly handle it then why are you trying to do this instead of just using the `aws_ami_id` data source instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use `aws_ami_id` instead of `aws_ami_ids` so that `terraform apply` fails if the AMI is gone, forcing you to update your Terraform solution.

OR

2) Create two `aws_ami_ids` data sources (the second being a fallback), concat the results and take the first item. But, as [ydaetskcoR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291321/ydaetskcor) hinted at, why would you want this implicit (possibly undetected) fallback?